# XSLT: Using a different way of processing within the current way of processing

Tags: xslt, templates, process

Below I'm trying to match certain nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="nodes">    
    <element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="nodes" mode="different" />
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, there are multiple ways of processing for the same nodes. I want to use this different way of processing **within** the current way of processing. That's why I perform `apply-templates` on the same selection, which is `nodes`, however the `mode` is different now.

Here's how the different mode could look like:

```
    <xsl:template match="nodes" mode="different">
<!-- another way of processing these nodes -->
</xsl:template>
```

Now, this does not work. Only the first type of processing is processed and the `apply-templates` call is simply not applied.

To be a bit more specific:

```
<xsl:template match="Foundation.Core.Association.connection">
    <xsl:for-each select="Foundation.Core.AssociationEnd">
        <someElement>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Foundation.Core.Association.connection" mode="different" />
        </someElement>      
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I select `Foundation.Core.Association.connection`. Of course this is wrong, but how do I refer to this element given the current element and position? Given Derek his comment, that should do it.

What am I doing wrong, how can I get what I want using XSLT? What could be another approach to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your xml look like?

Comment: the xml input is very complicated.. I'm using a for-each within a for-each and need to use attributes from the first for-each in my second for-each..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template match="Foundation.Core.Association.connection">
>
>     <xsl:for-each select="Foundation.Core.AssociationEnd">
>
>         <someElement> 
>                 <xsl:apply-templates
> ```
>
> select="Foundation.Core.Association.connection"
>   mode="different" />
>
> As you can see, I select
>   Foundation.Core.Association.connection.
>   Of course this is wrong, but how do I
>   refer to this element given the
>   current element and position?

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="different" />
```

**The element you want to process differently is the parent of the current node**.

**Of course, most likely this convoluted processing is not necessary at all**, which would be confirmed, had you been able to show more of the XML document and to formulate the problem in a more succint way.

Answer (score 1):

if "nodes" is referring to the same exact set of nodes in the containing match, try:

```
<xsl:template match="nodes">    
    <element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="different" />
    </element>
</xsl:template>
```